# Can we Use "Case" in a ColdFusion Query-of-Query

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, qoq

I am applying `case` in ColdFusion query of query but it's throwing an error.

**Query:**

```
<cfquery name="qEmployees1" dbtype="query">
    select (
        case 
          when ISNUMERIC(u.userdefined)=1
          then right('00000000'+u.userdefined,8)
          else userdefined
        end
      ) as hello
    from all_employees
    order by hello ASC
</cfquery>
```

**Error message:**

```
Encountered "when" at line 3, column 22. Was expecting one of: 
    "AND" ... "BETWEEN" ... "IN" ... "IS" ... "LIKE" ... "NOT" ... 
    "OR" ... ")" ... "=" ... "." ... "!=" ... "#" ... "<>" ... 
    ">" ... ">=" ... "<" ... "<=" ... "+" ... "-" ... "*" ... 
    "||" ... "/" ... "**" ... "(" ...
```

Comment: The query-of-query SQL is quite limited. Instead use a <cfif> tag to make conditional statements

Comment: @volumeone how can we use <cfif> instead of case?

Comment: What is the datatype of `all_employees.userdefined`? I'm guessing it's a varchar?

Comment: After looking at this again, I agree with @Ageax 's comment below. I don't think `cfif` will be doing what you think it's doing here. Since this is for CF2016, I changed my answer to include some newer options that get rid of the QoQ and duplicate the functionality being attempted.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

The original suggestion isn't going to work due to it only looking at a single row. Really you need to loop through your `all_employees` recordset and apply it to each individual row.

You might be able to achieve this without QoQ if you are just outputting the results to the page. Like this:

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop query="all_employees">
     <cfif isNumeric(all_employees.userdefined)>
      #Right('00000000'&all_employees.userdefined,8)#
     <cfelse>
      #all_employees.userdefined#
     <cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

**Original Answer:**

How about something like this?:

```
<cfquery name="qEmployees1" dbtype="query">
SELECT 
<cfif isNumeric([all_employees].[u.userdefined])>
  right('00000000'+u.userdefined,8) 
<cfelse>
 u.userdefined
</cfif> AS hello
FROM all_employees
ORDER by hello
</cfquery>
```

I have not tested this but I don't think having dot notation in the SQL column name will work correctly in this case. I enclosed it in square brackets anyway.

Comment: @volumeone - I don't think that is doing what you expect. A cfif within a query will be evaluated *before* the sql - not within the SQL. So the logic is not actually being applied to each value in the query.

Comment: Well, what do you know.... it bombs in ACF but actually *does* work in Lucee. Learn something new every day!

Comment: @Ageax I've always done it this way and its worked for me in ACF

Comment: I tried it with CF2016 on https://trycf.com and it errored.  Just retried it with 2018 and 11, and you're right that it runs without error under those versions. That said... it still doesn't produce the correct result. Unlike a database CASE, the CFIF only looks at the *1st row* in the query to see if it's numeric. It doesn't apply the logic to every row in the query separately. Swap the positions of the two rows and you'll see what I mean https://trycf.com/gist/63df5bdddd27a55581ca582eac6b95d2/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: Yes you're right it doesn't quite work. Looks like the OP edited to make it correct

Comment: It is not just the syntax. A normal CASE applies logic to each row in the table - *individually*. The CFIF on the other hand, just checks the value in the 1st row and essentially applies that same decision to ALL rows in the query. Would be easier to illustrate if SQLFiddle was up for SQL Server ;-)

Comment: @Ageax If SQL Fiddle goes down, there's always https://dbfiddle.uk. But the server is in the UK, so date formats will be different than US.

Comment: @Shawn - Thanks. Was trying to remember the url but was having a brain freeze!

Comment: @Ageax I use both of those quite a bit. They're great. But you have to remember that DBFiddle displays dates in dd/mm/yyyy. I can't tell you how many times I've tried pulling October 1 and ended up with 1/10 and smacked my head before realize date was default formatted differently. I've really started to appreciate ISO 8601. :-)

Comment: @TechleadzTeam I have updated the code with a different way of getting the results. It is not a QoQ but will output the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

I thought about this one and decided to change it to an actual answer. Since you're using CF2016+, you have access to some of the more modern features that CF offers. First, Query of Query is a great tool, but it can be *very* slow. Especially for lower record counts. And then if there are a lot of records in your base query, it can eat up your server's memory, since it's an in-memory operation. We can accomplish our goal without the need of a QoQ.

One way we can sort of duplicate the functionality that you're looking for is with some of the newer CF functions. `filter`, `each` and `sort` all work on a query object. These are the `member function` versions of these, but I think they look cleaner. Plus, I've used cfscript-syntax.

I mostly reused my original CFSCript query (all_employees), that creates the query object, but I added an `f` column to it, which holds the text to be filtered on.

```
all_employees = QueryNew("userdefined,hello,f", "varchar,varchar,varchar",
    [
      ["test","pure text","takeMe"],
      ["2","number as varchar","takeMe"],
      ["03","leading zero","takeMe"],
      [" 4 ","leading and trailing spaces","takeMe"],
      ["5        ","extra trailing spaces","takeMe"],
      ["        6","extra leading spaces","takeMe"],
      ["aasdfadsf","adsfasdfasd","dontTakeMe"],
      ["165e73","scientific notation","takeMe"],
      ["1.5","decimal","takeMe"],
      ["1,5","comma-delimited (or non-US decimal)","takeMe"],
      ["1.0","valid decimal","takeMe"],
      ["1.","invalid decimal","takeMe"],
      ["1,000","number with comma","takeMe"]

    ]
) ;
```

The original base query didn't have a `WHERE` clause, so no additional filtering was being done on the initial results. But if we needed to, we could duplicate that with `QueryFilter` or `.filter`.

```
filt = all_employees.filter( function(whereclause){ return ( whereclause.f == "takeMe"); } ) ;
```

This takes the `all_employees` query and applies a function that will only return rows that match our function requirements. So any row of the query where `f == "takeMe"`. That's like `WHERE f = 'takeMe'` in a query. That sets the new filtered results into a new query object `filt`.

Then we can use `QueryEach` or `.each` to go through every row of our new filtered query to modify what we need to. In this case, we're building a new array for the values we want. A `for/in` loop would probably be faster; I haven't tested.

```
filt.each(
        function(r) {
            retval.append(
                ISNUMERIC(r.userDefined) ? right("00000000"&ltrim(rtrim((r.userdefined))),8) : r.userDefined
            ) ;
        }
    )  ;
```

Now that we have a new array with the results we want, the original QoQ wanted to order those results. We can do this with `ArraySort` or `.sort`.

```
retval.sort("textnocase") ;
```

In my test, CF2016 seemed to pass `retval.sort()` as a boolean and didn't return the sorted array, but CF2018 did. This was expected behavior, since the return type was changed in CF2018. Regardless, both will sort the `retval` array, so that when we dump the `retval` array, it's in the chosen order.

And as I always suggest, load test on your system with your data. Like I said, this is only one way to go about what you're trying to do. There are others that may be faster.

https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=dedd219b-6b27-451d-972a-7af75c25d897/54e5559a-b42e-4bf6-b19b-075bfd17bde2/67c0856d-bdb3-4c92-82ea-840e6b8b0214.cfm

(CF2018) > https://trycf.com/gist/2a3762dabf10ad695a925d2bc8e55b09/acf2018?theme=monokai

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/queryfilter.html

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/queryeach.html

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arraysort.html

**ORIGINAL:**

This is more of a comment than an answer, but it's much too long for a comment.

I wanted to mention a couple of things to watch out for.

First, ColdFusion's `isNumeric()` can sometimes have unexpected results. It doesn't really check to see if a value is a number. It checks if a string can be converted to number. So there are all sorts of values that `isNumeric()` will see as `numeric`. EX: `1e3` is scientific notation for `1000`. `isNumeric("1e3")` will return `true`.

My second suggestion is how to deal with leading and trailing space in a "numeric" value, EX: `" 4 "`. `isNumeric()` will return `true` for this one, but when you append and trim for your final value, it will come out as `"000000 4"`. My suggestion to deal with these is to use `val()` or `ltrim(rtrim())` around your column. `val()` will reduce it to a basic number (`" 1.0 " >> "1"`) but `ltrim(rtrim())` will retain the number but get rid of the space (`" 1.0 " >> "1.0"`) and also retain the "scientific notation" value (`" 1e3 " >> "1e3"`). Both still miss `1,000`, so if that's a concern you'll need to handle that. But the method you use totally depends on the values your data contains. Number verification isn't always as easy as it seems it should be.

I've always been a firm believer in GIGO -- Garbage In, Garbage Out. I see basic data cleansing as part of my job. But if it's extreme or regular, I'll tell the source to fix it or their stuff won't work right. When it comes to data, it's impossible to account for all possibilities, but we can check for common expectations. It's always easier to whitelist than it is to blacklist.

```
<cfscript>
all_employees = QueryNew("userdefined,hello", "varchar,varchar",
    [
      ["test","pure text"],
      ["2","number as varchar"],
      ["03","leading zero"],
      [" 4 ","leading and trailing spaces"],
      ["5        ","extra trailing spaces"],
      ["        6","extra leading spaces"],
      ["165e73","scientific notation"],
      ["1.5","decimal"],
      ["1,5","comma-delimited (or non-US decimal)"],
      ["1.0","valid decimal"],
      ["1.","invalid decimal"],
      ["1,000","number with comma"]

    ]
)

//writedump(all_employees) ;

retval = [] ;

for (r in all_employees) {
    retval.append(
        {
          "1 - RowInput"   : r.userdefined.replace(" ","*","all") , // Replace space with * for output visibility.
          "2 - IsNumeric?" : ISNUMERIC(r.userdefined) ,
          "3 - FirstOutput": ( ISNUMERIC(r.userDefined) ? right("00000000"&r.userdefined,8) : r.userDefined ) ,
          "4 - ValOutput"  : ( ISNUMERIC(r.userDefined) ? right("00000000"&val(r.userdefined),8) : r.userDefined ) ,
          "5 - TrimOutput"  : ( ISNUMERIC(r.userDefined) ? right("00000000"&ltrim(rtrim((r.userdefined))),8) : r.userDefined )
        } 
    ) ;
}

writeDump(retval) ;
</cfscript>
```

https://trycf.com/gist/03164081321977462f8e9e4916476ed3/acf2018?theme=monokai

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else decides to try [the QoQ below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53118993/8895292), one very important thing to note is that even *if* it executes without error, it's NOT doing the same thing as [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). A `CASE` statement applies logic to the values within each row of a table - *individually*. In the QoQ version, the CFIF expression does not operate on all values within the query. It *only* examines the value in the 1st row and then applies the decision for that one value to ALL rows in the query.

Notice how the QoQ below (incorrectly) reports that all of the values are numeric? While the database query (correctly) reports a mix of "Numeric" and "Non-numeric" values. So the QoQ code is *not* equivalent to CASE.

**TestTable Data:**

```
id  userDefined
1   22
2   AA
3   BB
4   CC
```

**Database Query:**

```
   SELECT CASE
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(userDefined)=1 THEN 'Number: '+ userDefined
            ELSE 'Not a number: ' + userDefined
        END AS TheColumnAlias
   FROM TestTable
   ORDER BY ID ASC
```

**Database Query Result:**

[image: Database Query Result]

**QoQ**

```
<cfquery name="qQueryOfQuery" dbtype="query">
  SELECT 
      <cfif isNumeric(qDatabaseQuery2.userDefined)>
         'Number: '+ userDefined
      <cfelse>
         'Not a number: ' + userDefined
      </cfif>
      AS TheColumnAlias
   FROM qDatabaseQuery2
   ORDER by ID
</cfquery>
```

**QoQ Result**

[image: QoQ Result]

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly?  Please share some context of the goal for your post.

To me it looks like your query may not be formatted properly.  It would evalusate to something like:

```
    select ( 0000000099
      ) as hello
    from all_employees
    order by hello ASC
```

Try doing this.  Put a `<cfabort>` right here... And then let me know what query was produced on the screen when you run it.

```
<cfquery name="qEmployees1" dbtype="query">
    select (
        case 
          when ISNUMERIC(u.userdefined)=1
          then right('00000000'+u.userdefined,8)
          else userdefined
        end
      ) as hello
    from all_employees
    order by hello ASC
<cfabort>
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Are you sure that cfabort is in the right place?  Also, are you sure that QofQ supports case constructs?

Comment: Yeah, remember QoQ's are not the same as a database query. Although your dbms (Sql Server, MySQL, etc...) may support CASE, Adobe QoQ'a do not. QoQ's are VERY limited.

Answer (score -1):

```
<cfquery name="qEmployees1" dbtype="query">
  SELECT 
    (
      <cfif isNumeric(all_employees.userdefined)>
         right('00000000'+all_employees.userdefined,8) 
      <cfelse>
         all_employees.userdefined
      </cfif>
    ) AS hello
FROM all_employees
ORDER by hello
</cfquery>
```

it is the syntax free answer thanks to @volumeone

Comment: I stand corrected. *Technically* it runs without error under some versions of ACF, but..  doesn't return the same result as a dbms CASE.

Comment: You might not even need a QoQ if you're just outputting to the page. I updated my answer